# How to trigger NodeJS service based on user's calendar event

Tags: node.js, calendar, google-calendar-api, webhooks, pipedream

I am trying to allow a user to log in to a web app with their calendar service (eg. Google Calendar, Outlook) and then whenever one of their calendar events start or end, I want a NodeJS service to be triggered.

My thinking was to try to use `pipedream.com` (though only an idea, very happy to use another approach) in the following fashion:

```
1. User logs in to their calendar service via my web app, or perhaps provides a webhook or equivalent
2. I store their calendar credentials and then pass them to a service such as Pipedream
3. On calendar event start or end, Pipedream then triggers my NodeJS service
```

I am stuck working out how I can pass the user's calendar credentials/webhook to Pipedream, as it requires login at the point of setup:
[image: Screenshot of Pipedream]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is pipedream a requirement for this project? Firebase has some nice Cloud Functions triggers that would work well for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Nope it is not at all, just an idea to use Pipedream. Thanks a lot @Harry will look into those!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase cloud functions would be a good solution here. The Cloud Functions triggers allow execution of a serverless node.js function to be [triggered at a specific time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), in a very simple way:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

The big advantage is that you only pay for the execution time of your function, so you don't need to worry about a server sitting idle until the time of the meeting (which triggers the function).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @Harry! This looks great, but how are you imagining that it would be triggered by calendar events? Are you thinking that I would try to continually grab the user's calendar events and then setup cronjobs based on event's start and finish times?

Comment: Yes, exactly - you can automate that. Just pull the event times into a database (e.g. Cloud Firestore if you're staying in the Firebase ecosystem) and use another function that is triggered when a new event is added to grab the time of the event and schedule the cronjob.

Comment: If this seems like a solution for you, please feel free to mark the question as solved and/or upvote the answer.

Comment: Sure have upvoted. Am looking into whether there is a more simple solution (eg. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) and if not, will go ahead with yours and tick it